# how to create an berkeley db using java

Tags: berkeley-db

i am new to berkeley db . i have installed the berkely db using [link text](http://www.techsww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/berkeleydb/installation/installing_berkeleydb_on_ubuntu_linux.php)

so i need to create my first db i have checked the sample programs but i coudnt find it easy please help me to create an sample db ...and how to use the API for java

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to read the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/index.html) starting with the [Getting Started Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg/C/BerkeleyDB-Core-C-GSG.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to read the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/index.html) starting with the [Getting Started Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg/C/BerkeleyDB-Core-Java-GSG.pdf).